# Why does my JavaScript no longer clear the value of an input box when I comment out an alert on the previous line?

Tags: jquery

I wrote a js and it look like

```
$('#searchform').keydown( function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == '13' ) {
        submitForm();
        return;
    }else if ( event.which == '27' ){
        alert("ESC keydown TO DO - Clear the contents from search box ");
        $('#id_search').val('');
    }
});
```

This will remove contents of that input box, **but when i comment alert message**, it will not. Could you please explain me why??

Comment: That shouldn't happen. How are you commenting out the line? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Maybe the event is interfering somehow? You could try cancelling the event, and / or starting a timer and clearing the box 10ms later.

Comment: @Pekka i comment out line by //this

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/R7Z9j/) - please post more of your code, jsFiddle live example where this problems happens will be good.

Comment: Off topic - your code can be improved if you change `event.which == '13'` to `event.which === 13` it's better practice and better efficiency.

Comment: @ShadowWizard See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/R7Z9j/2/

Comment: This is probably a timing issue of some sort, although I'm not entirely sure why

Comment: @user1066679 Your jsFiddle works for me, which browser are you using?

Comment: See Shadow Wizard's comment (Can't reproduce). On my FF9.0.1 the text box clears with and without the alert

Comment: @user1066679 What about [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7Z9j/2/)? I saw it. Pressing ESC show alert and clears the box. Good. We can't solve anything because we can't see any problem.

Comment: @user1066679: you haven’t shown us a problem yet. See http://jsfiddle.net/R7Z9j/7/ — the alert is commented out, but when I press return (in Chrome 16 on the Mac), the text in the input disappears. Do you get a different result using that fiddle? If so, which browser version are you using?

Comment: @ShadowWizard and Paul D. Waite I mean if you remove that alert, it will not clear the input field. and i'm using firefox 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, figured out what happens.

In Firefox browser, the flow of events is:

1. User press the <kbd>ESC</kbd> key.
2. The `keydown` event handler is called, **value is changed to empty string**.
3. The textbox value is "recalculated" as the keyup event occurs, resulting in the previous value.

In other words, you can't directly change the value during `keydown` event.

One simple workaround is using a timer, changing the value after a millisecond:

```
$('#searchform').keydown( function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == '13' ) {
        submitForm();
        return;
    }else if ( event.which == '27' ){
        //alert("ESC keydown TO DO - Clear the contents from search box ");
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            $('#id_search').val('');
        }, 1);
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7Z9j/10/).

Comment: Work like magic. Thank you for this.  
But still get error on firefox 3.6.

Anyway thanks for this

Comment: Firefox 3.6 is like IE6 maybe even worse. **[UPGRADE](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all-older.html)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#searchform').keydown( function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == '13' ) {
        submitForm();
        return;
    }else if ( event.which == '27' ){
        $('#id_search', this).val(''); // this line was your problem. `$('#id_search', this)` referred the input field with the form with which the event binded
    }
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/owuxev/2/edit#source)

Comment: @user1066679 please check the live demo